# Write a replaceTokensWithStrings: method with varargs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to do the following:

```
["Hello <firstname> <middlename> <lastname>". replaceTokensWithStrings: 
  @"firstname", someFirstName, 
  @"middlename", middleNameMightBeNilObject,
  @"lastname", lastNameObject];
```

It looks like this is not possible because of the "`nil` as a terminator problem".

However `NSLog` also takes multiple arguments and can handle `nil` as parameters too:

```
NSString *nilValue = nil;

NSLog(@"Value of nilValue=%@", nilValue);
```

output

```
Value of nilValue=(null)
```

So how can I achieve this in my `replaceTokensWithStrings:...` method?

**Update: The signature of my method:**

```
-(NSString *)replaceTokensWithStrings:(NSString *)input, ... NS_SOMETHING_SPECIAL_HERE{
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSLog` counts the number of format specifiers (`%@`, `%i`, etc.) in its format string (the first argument, the literal string) in order to know how many arguments it should pull off the call stack. This is why it can handle `nil` arguments -- it is using the count to terminate its processing (and, incidentally, why it will often crash if you give it too few arguments).

Since you have a format-type string, you can do the same thing -- just whip up a helper method that counts the number of `<something>` elements in the string on which `replaceTokensWithStrings:` has been called, and use the results to limit your processing of the `va_list`.

The `NS_SOMETHING_SPECIAL` in your method declaration would be `NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION` for the case where you're using `nil` as a sentinel. You don't need anything special if you're getting the count of arguments from somewhere.

Comment: Very insightful, I was wondering what NSLog does differently and I was assuming it is an **"Oh I am part of the framework and am allowed to do stuff you ain't"**-thing

Answer (score 1):

Can't you change nil to be @"" so it will replace with a blank string?

Comment: nil might be a value that is returned from elsewhere so i would have to replace every parameter before every call. So this is not an option. But good remark --> I updated my question accordingly

Comment: In that case, it might be a good idea to make your variable arguments into an NSArray of arguments. Variable argument lists always treat nil as the terminator, and to the best of my knowledge there's no way to alter this.

Comment: this is also the case for an NSArray, you can't add nil there either.

Comment: If the users of that function call really want null in their list, they can use NSNull

Answer (score 1):

Don't work?

```
["Hello <firstname> <middlename> <lastname>". replaceTokensWithStrings: 
  @"firstname", @"Peter", 
  @"middlename", @"", // or myStr
  @"lastname", @"Smith"];
```

or check value:

```
@"middlename", myStr ? myStr : @"",
```

---

#### EDIT:

If you want variable parameters, you should read http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/variable-argument-lists-in-cocoa.html

Comment: I updated my question with the method signature. I want to use varargs (...) with my function. Similar to `NSLog(@"string", obj1, obj2, ...);`

Comment: @best see update or go to http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/variable-argument-lists-in-cocoa.html.